# Zend_Db_Table - Update don't work

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

The code seems not working.

```
// $counter is an instance of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
$counter->update(array('hits' => 'hits+1'), '"id" = 1');
```

I took a look into the DB profiler and find the following query:

```
UPDATE `downloads` SET `hits` = ? WHERE ("id" = 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an instance of `Zend_Db_Expr` (an SQL expression) to get this to work (untested):

```
$counter->update(array('hits' => new Zend_Db_Expr( 'hits+1' ) ), 'id = 1');
```

... or something similar I believe should work. Report back if it doesn't work, and I'll come up with a tested answer.

**UPDATE:**
Ok, I tested it, and it works, provided that you loose the quotes around `id` in the where clause. `id` shouldn't be interpreted as a literal string but as a column name. Maybe you ment to use backticks in stead? Like so '`id` = 1'. That is the proper way to quote an identifier for MySQL.